# Как задать константу в padding ссылки

Tags: html, css

У меня есть константа объявленная как

```
* { --offset: 10px; }
```

И я хочу задать, при наведении на ссылку, смещение на константу, чтобы вместо

```
.menu a:hover {
   padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
}
```

я мог написать

```
.menu a:hover {
   padding: var(--offset) 0 var(--offset) var(--offset)*2;
}
```

Возможно ли вообще такое реализовать?

Comment: Если писать 
`.menu a:hover { padding: var(--offset); }`, то смещение работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в умножении константы на числовой литерал.
Если писать

```
.menu a:hover { padding: var(--offset) 0 var(--offset) 20; }
```

то все работает хорошо. Так же к константе можно прибавлять литерал, то есть если написать

```
.menu a:hover { padding: var(--offset) 0 var(--offset) var(--offset)+10; }
```

будет тоже работать.

Comment: Не используйте переменные в CSS. Очень слабая поддержка браузерами